# Clojure - using map recursively

Tags: clojure, nested-lists

If I have a list, I can use `map` to apply a function to each item of the list.

```
(map sqrt (list 1 4 9))

(1 2 3)
```

I can also use `map` in front of a list of lists:

```
(map count (list (list 1 2 3) (list 4 5)))

(4 5)
```

Now is there a way to apply `sqrt` to each number in the list of lists? I want to start from

```
(list (list 1 4 9) (list 16 25))
```

and obtain

```
((1 2 3)(4 5))
```

However, the following does not seem to work,

```
(map (map sqrt) (list (list 1 4 9) (list 16 25)))
```

nor the following.

```
(map (fn [x] (map sqrt x)) (list (list 1 4 9) (list 16 25)))
```

Why? (And how do I solve this?)

Comment: Your last snippet does work. What error message do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second to last version "nearly" works.  Clojure has no automatic
currying, so `(map sqrt)` is *not* partial application, but `(map sqrt)`
returns a transducer, which takes one argument and returns a function
with three different arities - so running your code there will give you
back a function for each list of numbers.

To make that work, you can use `partial`:

```clj
user=> (map (partial map sqrt) (list (list 1 4 9) (list 16 25)))
((1 2 3) (4 5))
```

And of course there is the obligatory [specter](https://github.com/redplanetlabs/specter) answer:

```clj
user=> (transform [ALL ALL] sqrt '((1 4 9)(16 25)))
((1 2 3) (4 5))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write recursive function for this task:

```
(defn deep-map [f seq1]
  (cond (empty? seq1) nil
        (sequential? (first seq1))
        (cons (deep-map f (first seq1))
              (deep-map f (rest seq1)))
        :else (cons (f (first seq1))
                    (deep-map f (rest seq1)))))
```

Example:

```
(deep-map #(Math/sqrt %) '((1 4 9) (16 25 36)))
=> ((1.0 2.0 3.0) (4.0 5.0 6.0))
```

Or you can use [`clojure.walk`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.walk) and function [`postwalk`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.walk/postwalk):

```
(clojure.walk/postwalk
  #(if (number? %) (Math/sqrt %) %)
  '((1 4 9) (16 25 36)))

=> ((1.0 2.0 3.0) (4.0 5.0 6.0))
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `map` is closely related to the function `for`, which I think is sometimes easier to use.  Here is how I would solve this problem:

```
  (let [matrix [[1 4 9]
                [16 25]]
        result (vec (for [row matrix]
                      (vec (for [num row]
                             (Math/sqrt num)))))]
    result)
```

with result:

```
result => 
    [[1.0 2.0 3.0] 
     [4.0 5.0]]
```

If you remove the two `(vec ...)` bits, you'll see the same result but `for` normally returns a lazy sequence.

Answer (score 1):

@MartinPuda's answer is right.

The tail call recursive version is here:

```
(defn map* [f sq & {:keys [acc] :or {acc '()}}]
  (cond (empty? sq) (vec (reverse acc))
        (sequential? (first sq)) (map* f 
                                       (rest sq)
                                       :acc (cons (map* f (first sq)) acc))
        :else (map* f (rest sq) :acc (cons (f (first sq)) acc))))
```

By tradition in lisp, such recursively into the nested structure going functions are `fnname*` (marked by an asterisk at the end).
`acc` accumulates the result nested tree which is constructed by `cons`.

In your case this would be:

```
(map* Math/sqrt (list (list 1 4 9) (list 16 25)))
```

Test with:

```
(map* (partial + 1) '[1 2 [3 4 [5] 6] 7 [8 [9]]])

;; => [2 3 [4 5 [6] 7] 8 [9 [10]]]
```